# Can't SSH into server over internet while server is connected to VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, transmission

So I have Transmission running on my Ubuntu 13.04 server that is connected to a VPN via OpenVPN. The problem is I want to be able to access the server over the internet, but it won't work while the VPN is running. For example, I want to be able to connect to a minecraft server running on the server from outside my network. I have port forwarding set correctly, however it times out while connecting to the server over the internet while the VPN connection is active on the server.

I only need Transmission routing through the VPN, is there a way to do this?
Thanks!